# Executing result of a Kusto command

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Let's say I have a Kusto command that has a resultset with a single row and a single column; and the value is a string that's a valid command (starting with a dot) in itself -- meaning that if I copy paste that string value into Kusto Explorer window and execute, it will be successfully executed. So is there a way to just execute it as part of the main command itself ? So I want to specify that the output of my command has to be executed as a command as well. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with current capabilities, you'll need to perform that in 2 separate steps: one - runs the initial query and captures its output; two - invokes that output.

you can write a simple script/program that does that using Kusto's API.